# Put png map image as a background to draw upon

Tags: qgis, google-maps, georeferencing, image

I have an image of a fiber optics network map:

[image]

I want to turn this map image (without any actual GIS data) into a vector map where each point is defined by lat, long.

To do this, I'm trying to import it in QGIS. I'm using the OpenLayers plugin to have Google maps as a basemap layer. I have an empty vector layer with projection set to EPSG:3857 where I want to draw the points.

I can't import the image and position it correctly over the Google Maps basemap.

As suggested, I tried [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html), placing 5 points (4 at the edges and 1 at the center).

I import the map guessing the coordinate system to be `Any idea what projection was used to create that map?

I tried both pasting coordinates in this format `48.767479, -97.551781` (found on Bing Maps searching the name of the cities) and in this format `48 46 02.92, -097 33 06.41` found using [this converter](http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx).

In both cases, I end up with a super small, distorted map off the coast of Gabon.

I also tried picking coordinates from [this webpage](https://epsg.io/3857/map) instead, which gives me projected coordinates in EPSG:3857, and feeding them to the Georeferencer plugin worked. However, my image is now very distorted when shown on top of the Google Maps (or Bing Maps) layer.

I guess the projection is not Mercator. Any idea on how I can work on this map without the distortion?

[image: Stretched image on map]

Comment: I can see this might ask the same question. But the answer to that question is 3 lines long and links to an [off-site tutorial](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-georeferencing-topo-sheets.html) that has been "moved" somewhere else. And that tutorial deals with placing polygons instead of lines. Oh, and it does not explain how to stretch the image over Google Maps, but assumes I know the coordinates of some points of my map already. Mhhh, not what I need?

Comment: If you edit the question, and explain why that is a different issue, it will likely be reopened.

Comment: The 'moved' tutorial had a link right at the top of where it moved to. I've updated the answer to give the new link as well. Bottom line, you are trying to georeference an image as a first step to then digitize the information on it. The tutorial explains georeferencing. The difference between creating lines and polygons (or points for that matter) is trivial - the point is you'll be drawing on top of the image. Also note Google Maps uses a projection/CRS (EPSG 3857, Web or Psuedo Mercator, lower right corner of your screenshot) that isn't well conducive to creating data.

Comment: @ChrisW I edited this with my attempts to follow the tutorial. No luck, I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your last attempt looks very promising. With more than 5 points you might get an even better picture.

I use this transformation settings:

[image]

Using as many border points as possible for georeferencing, I take the coordinates from the map canvas with the middle icon:

[image]

and get this picture (with clipping to GADM borders):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I added more than 10 points, but I still can't get it to match the Google Maps borders very well. I used EPSG 3857 coordinates to open the image in the Georeferencer plugin, set the points and to export back to QGIS them. It's the only combination that somehow worked (maybe it's a plugin bug, for other coordinates it sometimes crashed too). After doing this I tried changing the project properties. Is it too late now?

Comment: It might help if you take the border points from the google map background to georeference. EPSG:3857 is correct for that. The city points might be the point of the fibre optic network switch, and not the town center.

Comment: I'm confused. Is there a way that I can specify the points using EPSG:3857 and then work on the map without distorting it? Is there a chance to use a basemap that matches the projection used in the image? Thanks.

Comment: The Georeferencer offers you an icon labelled `From map canvas`. All you have to do is search for the point on the base map, and click on it (and set the CRS in `Settings -> Transformation Settings` to EPSG:3857 as well).

Comment: I can't find any icon labelled `From map canvas` in the Georeferencer. Your results seem better than mine (my map is more distorted). I set the project CRS, the map layer CRS to EPSG:3857. I set EPSG:3857 when importing the image in the Georeferencer and when exporting it in the `Transformation settings`. However, your results look better than mine.  Could you provide a download link to the project and\or the GCP points you used in the Georeferencer? The georeferenced `.tiff` image would be OK too (maybe you can 7zip it to prevent the host from messing with the upload). Thanks.